# tangents conditions

Tags: functions, tangent-line

what are the condition for a tangent to be exist .
Is it necessary for the function to be continous.

but it is necessary to be continous for a function to be differentiable at that point .

can anybody tell me the basic concept about all this

Comment: I have also the same doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function has a tangent at $a$ if and only if it is differentiable at $a$. A function is continuous at $a$ if it is differentiable at $a$. (But note a function can be continuous at $a$ but not differentiable there.) Thus you are right that for a function to have a tangent at $a$ it must be continuous at $a$.

---

In response to your comments below:

The tangent line to a function $f$ at $a$ is given by $$f(a)+(x-a)f'(a).$$ Its slope is the derviative of $f$ at $a$.

The derivative cannot be infinite since by definition, the derivative of $f$ at $a$, denoted $f'(a)$ is

$$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

provided the limit exists and is **finite**.

The fact that the derivative is finite does not prevent it going to infinity. That is while we cannot have $f'(a)=\infty$, we can have $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=\infty$. For example if $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is the function given by $f(x)=\ln x$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$ then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}=\infty.$$

The slope of the tangent lines goes to infinity in the limit. To put it another way, the tangent lines limit to a vertical line. Note that $f'(0)$ is not even defined (and so cannot be infinite) because $f(0)$ is not defined ($0$ is not in the domain of the function $f$). In fact there is no choice of $f(0)$ for which $f$ would be differentiable at $0$.

Comment: how can it be possible if a function is continous but not differentiable

Comment: The function given by $|x|$ is continuous at $x=0$ but not differentiable there. (I am not sure if that answered your question, because your question is not worded very clearly.)

Comment: and if the tangent is vertical then is it differentiable

Comment: No, you cannot have a vertical tangent because you cannot have an infinite derivative. (The slope of the tangent line is the derivative, which is always finite.)

Comment: then what is the tangent of x=5

Comment: For what function?

Comment: f(x) = 5 is the function

Comment: That is very different to $x=5$! The function given by $f(x)=5$ is a constant function and has zero derivative everywhere. The tangent line coincides with the function everywhere.

Comment: sorry what is the tangent for the line x=5

Comment: The line $x=5$ is not the graph of a function. Remember a function takes a unique value for every point in its domain. The line takes infinitely many $y$-values for $x=5$.

Comment: but it can we plotted on graph

Comment: or tangent at x = 0 for f(x)=log x

Comment: Many things can be plotted that are not functions. You need to review the definition of a function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)

Comment: The formula $\log x$ is not defined at $x=0$, so you have not defined the value of your function $f$ at zero and therefore it does not make sense to talk about the derivative there. You can say that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\log x=\infty$, but this is different to saying "$f'(0)=\infty$".

Comment: So can there be tangents of plotted curve but they are not function

Comment: And what is the tangent of log x     when x approaches to 0

Comment: Please see the edit. Hopefully it answers all your questions.